# Call operator new[] using GDB

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, new-operator, gdbserver

How can I call to `operator new[]` with GDB?

For example I want to allocate  0x40 bytes and print the address : `operator new[](0x44u));`

How can I do that using GDB ?

When I tried `p (void*)operator new[](0x40)` I got `No symbol "operator" in current context.`

Comment: Does `p (void*)operator new[](0x40)` not work?

Comment: `No symbol "operator" in current context.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
(gdb) p 'operator new<TAB>
operator new(unsigned long)
operator new(unsigned long) [clone .cold]
...
operator new[](unsigned long)
operator new[](unsigned long)@got.plt
operator new[](unsigned long)@plt
operator new[](unsigned long, std::align_val_t)
... more choices

(gdb) p 'operator new[](unsigned long)'(0x40)
$1 = (void *) 0x416ee0
```